# View pager using fragmentstatepageradapter unable to set height according to the content of individual fargement

Tags: android, android-viewpager

View Pager using FragmentStatePagerAdapter to load fragments,loading data dynamically i.e every fragment has different data,so each fragment height needs to be adjusted according to content of individual fragment.
Method which i tried:
If you setTag(position) in the instantiateItem of your PageAdapter:

```
 @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int page) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_item , null);
        view.setTag(page);
```

//This R.layout.page_item is the layout of content of view pager item which all the fragments are using.
then can retrieve the view (page of the adapter) with an OnPageChangeListener, measure it, and resize your ViewPager:

```
private ViewPager pager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    pager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            resizePager(position);
        }
    });

    public void resizePager(int position) {
        View view = pager.findViewWithTag(position);
        if (view == null) 
            return;
        view.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        int width = view.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
            //The layout params must match the parent of the ViewPager 
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width , height); 
        pager.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

With this method height is getting changed,but the problem which i am facing is:
for the first time when i open my activity containg view pager,the first item's height of view pager is not getting changed but from second item height changes and when i swipe back in view pager,then the first item height is getting changed.

Problem-2:
My View Pager is inside relativeLayout--
Height and Width of Relative layout--match parent
Height and Width of ViewPager---Height--wrapcontent(although view pager doesnt support wrapcontent),width is match parent.

Layout of content fragment of view pager--

```
<Relative layout height=wrap-content,width=matchparent>
<Scroll-view height=match parent,width=matchparent>
<LinearLayout height,width=wrap-content/></ScrollView></relativeLayout>
```

As told height changes from second element but dont know why it occupies entire page i.e it becomes more big then before.

Please help in setting the view pager height of items according to the content size,if my approach is wrong do tell me how to set the height based upon content size.

I have solved one problem f layout becoming bigger from second item of view pager,there was some problem with layout of content fragment.But for the first time when view pager loads for the first item view pager height is not getting changed,from second item onwards height changes properly

Answer (score -1):

In your layout file, all your height attiributes for all views must be "wrap_content".

```
<RelativeLayout 
    height=wrap-content
    width=match_parent>
        <Scroll-view 
            height=wrap-content
            width=matchparent>
                  <LinearLayout 
                       height = "wrap_content"
                       width=wrap-content/>
         </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I have already tried by changing everything to wrap-content: it doesn't work